# Changing child attribute's element value through function without hardcode

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a `jsp` page with a table rows containing a button to increates or decrease integers:

```
<input type = "button" id="unique id" value="+" onclick="increase(this)
```

Each button contains a child with unique id  such as:

```
<div id="unique div id" align="center">2</div>
```

The function contains the following attempts to increase the `<div...>2</div>` to `<div...>3</div>`,`4`, and etc without passing hardcoded values into the function:

```
function increase(element){

 //attempt 1            
    document.getElementById((getElementsByTagName('div')[0].id)).innerHTML++;
    return false;

  //attempt 2
    //document.getElementById(document.getElementById(element.id).getElementsByTagName('div')[0].id).innerHTML++;
    //return false;
}
```

JSP body and table sample:

```
        <tr>
            <td>shirt</td>
            <td>1.11</td>
            <td>
            <input type="button" id="btn1" value="+" onclick="increase(this);" />
            <div id="1" align="center">2</div>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>pant</td>
            <td>2.22</td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="btn2" value="+" onclick="increase(this);" />
            <div id="2" align="center">3</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

[image]

Comment: `var div = element.querySelector("div").textContent++` https://jsfiddle.net/zxdbtpjq/ Those attempts look pretty arbitrary. Consider a thorough reading of a few beginner tutorials.

Comment: Oh, but your button is an input, and you say each button has a child div. That doesn't work. Post an actual, complete yet minimal example instead of these little fragments of code.

Comment: The `div` is not a child; it's a sibling of the button. So in your function... `element.nextElementSibling.textContent++`

Comment: Your latest recommendation worked for each row.